# DateTime and DateTime? object as a parameter

Tags: c#

I have one `Datetime?` and one `DateTime`, both of them calling the same method as follows. How should I approach to handle `System.DateTime?` vs `System.DateTime` ?

**Main.cs**

```
void SelectStartDate(DateTime currentDate, Action<DateTime> setter)
{
  var dialog = new DatePickerDialogView(currentDate);
}

void SelectEndDate(DateTime? currentDate, Action<DateTime> setter)
{
  var dialog = new DatePickerDialogView(currentDate);
}
```

**DatePickerDialogView.cs**

```
public DatePickerDialogView(DateTime initDateTime)
{
    init = initDateTime;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by handle it?

Comment: Should I create two init methods one for nullable and other for not nullable?

Comment: that's up to you. we can't reasonably answer that.

Comment: What is the best way of doing it?

Comment: Where's the init method?

Comment: I mean class constructor

Comment: @hotspring that is up to your requirements, not for us to solve.

Comment: I just curious everything is same except one of them nullable and other is not. Please do not focus on the requirement. I am trying to learn.

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this:

```
public DatePickerDialogView(DateTime? initDateTime)
{
    init = initDateTime.HasValue? initDateTime.Value : DateTime.Now;  //default to current date
}
```

I do not understand why you need 2 different implementations of `SelectStartDate`. Just use this one and remove the other one.

```
void SelectEndDate(DateTime? currentDate, Action<DateTime> setter)
```

Comment: Functionally equivalent alternative: `init = initDateTime.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now);`

Comment: Another one: `init = initDateTime ?? DateTime.Now;`

Answer (score 0):

Just do whatever you think is the best, but there are two possible solutions I would consider using.
First solution is that your `DatePickerDialogView` constructor takes `DateTime?` as parameter, then you can just check if it is null or not.
Another possibility is to check if `currentDate` in `SelectEndDate` method is null and do whatever you want to do with that information.